# How would I change this legacy SQL to standard?

Tags: google-bigquery

I would like to convert this legacy SQL code from Google BigQuery to standard SQL.  What do I need to change?

```
SELECT theme, COUNT(*) as count
FROM (
select UNIQUE(REGEXP_REPLACE(SPLIT(V2locations,';'), r',.*', '')) theme
  from [gdelt-bq:gdeltv2.gkg]
where DATE>20150302000000 and DATE < 20200609000000 and V2locations like '%Gabon%'   
AND V2themes like '%WB_133_INFORMATION_AND_COMMUNICATION_TECHNOLOGIES%'
)
group by theme
ORDER BY 2 DESC
LIMIT 300
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in BigQuery Standard SQL it will be

```
#standardSQL
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(V2location, r',.*', '') theme, COUNT(1) AS count
FROM `gdelt-bq.gdeltv2.gkg`, UNNEST(SPLIT(V2locations,';')) V2location
WHERE DATE > 20150302000000 AND DATE < 20200609000000 
AND V2location LIKE '%Gabon%'   
AND V2themes LIKE '%WB_133_INFORMATION_AND_COMMUNICATION_TECHNOLOGIES%'
GROUP BY theme
ORDER BY 2 DESC
LIMIT 300
```

pay attention of using `V2locations` vs. `V2location`